# connect xiami device to android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, xiaomi

I'm new to xiami and when I try searching for USB driver to connect to android studio and did not find any recent version and I try MI PC SUITE and it seems it did not work with new devices so can any xiami user tell me how they connect their devices to android studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just enabled Usb debugging, It will do all the things.